Russian pilot ejects over US, lives in some kind of bunker, befriends kids
As it says on the tin. Looking for, I believe, late 1980s, early 1990s movie about a Russian  pilot who ejects over the US. He lives and hides out in some kind of concrete bunker, possibly some kind of water/sewage construction. He befriends the local kids who are at first hostile towards him, and I think in the end they reveal him to their fathers.

The movie is called Russkies, starting Joaquin Phoenix, Whip Hubley, and Peter Billingsley (of Ralph/The Christmas Story fame). Great 80's flick
